# Which software allows me to perform hierarchical clustering manually?

Tags: gratis, ubuntu, data-visualization, web-services

I have 211 language names and I want to visualize them in a meaningful way. The first thing are language families, but besides that there are other "levels" of relationships.

Is there a software which allows me to create a tree out of those 211 items by drag-and-drop?

The software should be [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) and I have to be able to run it without problems (=> [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) or [web-services](/questions/tagged/web-services)). There should be an export option of the result. Preferably textual,  but if the graphics are good enough an image could be fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably looking for an [outliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outliner), a program that specializes in editing trees.

[Org-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode) is a famous example. Being Emacs-based, it comes with a learning curve, and I don’t think it can easily do drag-and-drop with a mouse. But it’s very powerful, works on essentially regular plain text files, and of course runs natively on Ubuntu.

There are many other options, as listed on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outliner).

Here’s what Org-mode can look like (showing like 10% of its feature set):

[image]